# Are armv8 and arm64 the same?

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-architecture, arm64

> In xcode which is the developement environment for iOS. When creating
> a new project. Build settings states that it supports **armv7**, **armv7s**
> and **arm64** architectures.

**The following chart shows apple devices architectures:**
[image]

**armv8** not mentioned anywhere. Does that mean **armv8** and **arm64** is the same thing?

> I wonna use the following binary:
> http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/Documentation/OfficialBinaries

It says that version 1.5.1 of this binary supports armv8 architecture. That also indicates that armv8 and arm64 are the same thing.

Another question but about the binary. Does the link indicates that its safe to use the 1.5.1 version for iOS?

Comment: If you look at http://iossupportmatrix.com you will see that 64-bit and ARMv8 are the same.

Comment: I got my answer thank you. can you please add an answer and mention libjpeg so I can give you a credit for it? Thanks again.

Comment: Arm Armv8 CPU architecture has three profiles. A, R, M.
aarch64 and aarch32 are the two CPU processor states that Armv8-A can support.

Answer (score 24):

Oh, ambiguous terminology - "architecture" in this context doesn't actually mean architecture in the sense of the ISA or system architecture laid down by ARM, what it really means is "iOS target", i.e. a particular system configuration and level of ISA support:

- "armv7" represents a certain configuration of the ARMv7-A architecture.
- "armv7s" represents a slightly different configuration of the ARMv7-A architecture, with more optional features present over the base "armv7" target.
- "arm64" represents the AArch64 state of the ARMv8-A architecture; there is no "armv8" target.

Comment: But how do you name packages, which are build on a 32-Bit system with ARMv8-A processor? Are they called `armhf`? But that's only an indicator for hard float feature in ARMv7, not for the extended instructions in `armv8`, isn't it?

Comment: What does "ISA" stand for?

Comment: @user920391 Instruction set architecture, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)

Answer (score 9):

No, the ARMv8-A instruction set (`armv8`) can also exist on 32-bit architecture, although I'm not aware of one example. So technically you can differentiate between them, like done in [docker](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64):

- ARMv5 32-bit (`arm32v5`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v5/
- ARMv6 32-bit (`arm32v6`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v6/ *(alias `armel`)*
- ARMv7 32-bit (`arm32v7`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v7/ *(alias `armhf`)*
- ARMv8 64-bit (`arm64v8`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm64v8/ *(alias `arm64`)*
- *ARMv8 32-bit (`arm32v8`): https://hub.docker.com/u/arm32v8/* and isn't supported and therefore has no packages.

Comment: Outside the Apple world, you certainly can build 32-bit ARM-mode or Thumb-mode code that takes advantage of features that ARMv8 introduced to 32-bit mode.  Like `gcc -mcpu=cortex-a53`.  Noticeable in instruction choice for std::atomic acquire / release loads vs. the ARMv7 code using barriers, for example.  https://godbolt.org/z/9Y46bM

Answer (score 0):

[ARM ISA structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzgeq.png)

Basically the 32-bit armv8-A instructions are called AArch32 and are fully compatible with ARMv7-A (32-bit), armv8-A is not the same as arm64 since this refers specifically to the AArch64 instructions contained within the armv8-A instruction set. See the image above